# Different Navigation Bar color

Tags: ios7, colors, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I would like to set for each view different color of NavigatioBar?

For example navbar is blue, when i push for the some view, so navbar be white, and when swipe back so navbar be back blue.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can set navigationbar bartintcolor on each controller's viewdidload method 
like

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];//Set color here
```